# What would be a formal reply to "I need your help"?

Tags: phrases, politeness, business-language

A colleague emailed me saying

> **I need your help**

but offering no further details. Now, what what be a formal reply to this which doesn't promise too much nor seem cold or unhelpful?

> a) Sure. How can I help?
>   b) Tell me?
>   c) Regarding?

Which one of the above seems most appropriate? Or there is some other sentence or phrase more appropriate for this kind of situation?

Comment: Too localised / not a real question / etiquette, not English language as such. Take your pick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer / reply should be based on your opinion of whether or not you want to help. If this is a trustworthy friend or colleague then your answer may be ...

*"Sure, what can I help you with?"* or *"Let me know what you need, I'd be glad to help."*

If in your opinion the friend is not trustworthy, then it may be ...

"Please let me know what you are needing help with."

Answer (score 2):

It mostly depends on your level of familiarity with your colleague.

If the two of you are on casual, friendly terms, any of those would be fine (although I'd change "*sure. How can I help?*" to "*Sure, how can I help?*").

However, if the two of you don't know each other all that well, something a bit more formal might be better, such as:

*I'm willing to help, but you'll need to furnish some details first*.

Comment: By the way, make sure you're not dealing with spam or a virus.  An email that vague sounds vaguely suspicious.

Comment: No, it was not spam/virus :)